# build failed while ant fresh install - DSpace 7.5

Tags: dspace

I want to perform ant fresh_install in my Windows 11, for my DSpace, however, it shows error like this

```
C:\DSpace-dspace-7.5\dspace\target\dspace-installer>ant fresh_install
ANT_OPTS is set to  -Djava.security.manager=allow
Buildfile: C:\DSpace-dspace-7.5\dspace\target\dspace-installer\build.xml

init_installation:

prepare_configs:
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\DSpace-dspace-7.5\dspace\target\dspace-installer\config-temp
     [copy] Copying 221 files to C:\DSpace-dspace-7.5\dspace\target\dspace-installer\config-temp
     [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\DSpace-dspace-7.5\dspace\target\dspace-installer\config-temp
     [copy] Copying 14 files to C:\DSpace-dspace-7.5\dspace\target\dspace-installer\config-temp

init_configs:
     [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\dspace\config
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\DSpace-dspace-7.5\dspace\target\dspace-installer\config-temp

test_database:
     [java] Failure during kernel init: Error creating bean with name 'org.dspace.importer.external.service.ImportService' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/DSpace-dspace-7.5/dspace/target/dspace-installer/lib/dspace-api-7.5.jar!/spring/spring-dspace-addon-import-services.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'pubmedImportService' while setting bean property 'importSources' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pubmedImportService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'liveImportClient'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.dspace.app.itemimport.BTEBatchImportService] for bean with name 'org.dspace.app.itemimport.BTEBatchImportService' defined in file [C:\dspace\config\spring\api\bte.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dspace.app.itemimport.BTEBatchImportService
     [java] 2023-06-09 16:54:26,907 WARN  org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext @ Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.dspace.importer.external.service.ImportService' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/DSpace-dspace-7.5/dspace/target/dspace-installer/lib/dspace-api-7.5.jar!/spring/spring-dspace-addon-import-services.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'pubmedImportService' while setting bean property 'importSources' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pubmedImportService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'liveImportClient'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.dspace.app.itemimport.BTEBatchImportService] for bean with name 'org.dspace.app.itemimport.BTEBatchImportService' defined in file [C:\dspace\config\spring\api\bte.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dspace.app.itemimport.BTEBatchImportService
     [java] org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.dspace.importer.external.service.ImportService' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/DSpace-dspace-7.5/dspace/target/dspace-installer/lib/dspace-api-7.5.jar!/spring/spring-dspace-addon-import-services.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'pubmedImportService' while setting bean property 'importSources' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pubmedImportService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'liveImportClient'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.dspace.app.itemimport.BTEBatchImportService] for bean with name 'org.dspace.app.itemimport.BTEBatchImportService' defined in file [C:\dspace\config\spring\api\bte.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dspace.app.itemimport.BTEBatchImportService
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:428)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:173)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1707)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953)
     [java]     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
     [java]     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
     [java]     at org.dspace.servicemanager.DSpaceServiceManager.startup(DSpaceServiceManager.java:277)
     [java]     at org.dspace.servicemanager.DSpaceKernelImpl.start(DSpaceKernelImpl.java:153)
     [java]     at org.dspace.servicemanager.DSpaceKernelImpl.start(DSpaceKernelImpl.java:128)
     [java]     at org.dspace.app.launcher.ScriptLauncher.main(ScriptLauncher.java:70)
     [java] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pubmedImportService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'liveImportClient'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.dspace.app.itemimport.BTEBatchImportService] for bean with name 'org.dspace.app.itemimport.BTEBatchImportService' defined in file [C:\dspace\config\spring\api\bte.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dspace.app.itemimport.BTEBatchImportService
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330)
     [java]     ... 18 more
     [java] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.dspace.app.itemimport.BTEBatchImportService] for bean with name 'org.dspace.app.itemimport.BTEBatchImportService' defined in file [C:\dspace\config\spring\api\bte.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dspace.app.itemimport.BTEBatchImportService
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1542)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:704)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:674)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1670)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:550)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:265)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1555)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1352)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656)
     [java]     ... 29 more
     [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dspace.app.itemimport.BTEBatchImportService
     [java]     at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
     [java]     at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
     [java]     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
     [java]     at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
     [java]     at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:496)
     [java]     at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:475)
     [java]     at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:284)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:469)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1607)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1534)
     [java]     ... 39 more
     [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failure during kernel init: Error creating bean with name 'org.dspace.importer.external.service.ImportService' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/DSpace-dspace-7.5/dspace/target/dspace-installer/lib/dspace-api-7.5.jar!/spring/spring-dspace-addon-import-services.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'pubmedImportService' while setting bean property 'importSources' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pubmedImportService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'liveImportClient'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.dspace.app.itemimport.BTEBatchImportService] for bean with name 'org.dspace.app.itemimport.BTEBatchImportService' defined in file [C:\dspace\config\spring\api\bte.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dspace.app.itemimport.BTEBatchImportService
     [java]     at org.dspace.app.launcher.ScriptLauncher.main(ScriptLauncher.java:82)
     [java] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.dspace.importer.external.service.ImportService' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/DSpace-dspace-7.5/dspace/target/dspace-installer/lib/dspace-api-7.5.jar!/spring/spring-dspace-addon-import-services.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'pubmedImportService' while setting bean property 'importSources' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pubmedImportService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'liveImportClient'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.dspace.app.itemimport.BTEBatchImportService] for bean with name 'org.dspace.app.itemimport.BTEBatchImportService' defined in file [C:\dspace\config\spring\api\bte.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dspace.app.itemimport.BTEBatchImportService
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:428)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:173)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1707)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953)
     [java]     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
     [java]     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
     [java]     at org.dspace.servicemanager.DSpaceServiceManager.startup(DSpaceServiceManager.java:277)
     [java]     at org.dspace.servicemanager.DSpaceKernelImpl.start(DSpaceKernelImpl.java:153)
     [java]     at org.dspace.servicemanager.DSpaceKernelImpl.start(DSpaceKernelImpl.java:128)
     [java]     at org.dspace.app.launcher.ScriptLauncher.main(ScriptLauncher.java:70)
     [java] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pubmedImportService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'liveImportClient'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.dspace.app.itemimport.BTEBatchImportService] for bean with name 'org.dspace.app.itemimport.BTEBatchImportService' defined in file [C:\dspace\config\spring\api\bte.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dspace.app.itemimport.BTEBatchImportService
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330)
     [java]     ... 18 more
     [java] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.dspace.app.itemimport.BTEBatchImportService] for bean with name 'org.dspace.app.itemimport.BTEBatchImportService' defined in file [C:\dspace\config\spring\api\bte.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dspace.app.itemimport.BTEBatchImportService
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1542)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:704)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:674)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1670)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:550)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:265)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1555)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1352)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656)
     [java]     ... 29 more
     [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dspace.app.itemimport.BTEBatchImportService
     [java]     at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
     [java]     at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
     [java]     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
     [java]     at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
     [java]     at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:496)
     [java]     at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:475)
     [java]     at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:284)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:469)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1607)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1534)
     [java]     ... 39 more

BUILD FAILED
C:\DSpace-dspace-7.5\dspace\target\dspace-installer\build.xml:770: Java returned: 1

Total time: 16 seconds
```

I have checked the Solr and Tomcat is active and workable, so I'm not sure what should I do to this error.

Hope you all can assist on this issue, I need to solve this installation for my assignment purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Please edit your Postgres `pg_hba.conf` and add the `host` line before any database ALL statement :

```
host     dspace  dspace     127.0.0.1/32    md5
```

That should work.